# Regex with Doctrine 2 query builder?

Tags: regex, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

As per the title, how would one match on a regular expression with the Doctrine 2 query builder? Basically I'm trying to generate unique slugs.

Here is my current implementation. I generate the slug. I then check to see if there are any slugs in use like this slug. If there are, I will append a -{number} to the end of the slug where {number} is the lowest number not already in use.

```
$qb->select(array('partial o.{id, slug}'))
   ->from('Foo\Bar\Entity\Object', 'o')
   ->where($qb->expr()->like('o.slug', ':slug'));

$slug = new SlugNormalizer($text);
$qb->setParameter('slug', $slug->__toString().'-%');
```

The problem here is LIKE slug% could match foo-bar-1, foo-bar-2, AND foo-bar-not-the-same-slug. What would be cleaner is a regex looking for REGEX slug-(\d+) or something similar.

Any way to do this with the Doctrine 2 query builder?

Answer (score 46):

install the [DoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions):

```
composer require beberlei/doctrineextensions
```

add the REGEXP configuration - update your app/config.yml

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                regexp: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Regexp
```

where ever your QueryBuilder is do this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('x');

return $qb->andWhere('REGEXP(x.your_property, :regexp) = true')
          ->setParameter('regexp', '[[:digit:]]{3}') // insert your own regex here
          ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

and don't forget to use SQL compatible regexes

Comment: It would be good to point a reference. https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

Answer (score 7):

REGEXP is a vendor specific function so Doctrine itself doesn't support it. Plus it's not a function so much as a comparison operator ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8811784/3334390)). But you can use the function on the field to compare with another value. [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) (written by a contributor to doctrine) has code to enable regular expression in MySQL.

Example from the File:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT A FROM Entity A WHERE REGEXP(A.stringField, :regexp) = 1');
$query->setParameter('regexp', '^[ABC]');
$results = $query->getArrayResult();
```

If you don't want to use DoctrineExtensions, you can write your own by following [this blog post](http://www.danieledangeli.com/enabling-mysql-regexp-in-symfony2/), or you can [look at the code for this Doctrine extension](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/Regexp.php) and write your own custom DQL function.

I have confirmed that REGEXP using DoctrineExtensions works great for my needs!

Answer (score -1):

Not tested (for MySQL):

```
$qb->where(new Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Comparison(
    'o.slug', 'REGEXP', ':slug')
);
$qb->setParameter('slug', '^'.$slug->__toString().'-[[:digit:]]+$');
```

Comment: This does not work. The Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Comparison class only has the following operators:     const EQ  = '=';
    const NEQ = '<>';
    const LT  = '<';
    const LTE = '<=';
    const GT  = '>';
    const GTE = '>=';    There is NO REGEXP option! Plus it's not a comparison operation ... why would it live there in the 1st place?

Comment: You're right, it does not work. But it's a comparison operation. Two operand, one operator between them, for me it is a comparison.

Comment: Ah, when you state it like that, maybe you're right. Could be a comparison op .. regardless, heh, it doesn't work. =[

Answer (score -1):

I did like this

```
 $query->andWhere('REGEXP(r.status, :text) = 1')
       ->orWhere('REGEXP(r.comment, :text) = 1')
       ->setParameter('text',MY REGULAR EXP);
```

Comment: What do you mean with the second parameter in `setParameter` (MY REGULAR EXP)?

Comment: setParameter is a method of doctrine.