# How to use RLIKE with Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, doctrine, rlike

I'm using Doctrine 2 (Doctrine ORM 2.1, to be more precise) with MySQL and want to find entries, beginning with a number. With native SQL I would write something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name RLIKE '^[0-9]';
```

But when I try to do it with DQL, I get the following error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 71: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'RLIKE'
#0 .../Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(396): Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException::syntaxError('line 0, col 73:...')
#1 .../Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(2746): Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser->syntaxError('=, <, <=, <>, >...')
#2 .../Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(2533): Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser->ComparisonOperator()
#3 .../Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(2071): Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser->ComparisonExpression()
#4 .../Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1994): Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser->SimpleConditionalExpression()
#5 .../Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1953): Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser->ConditionalPrimary()
#6 .../Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1927): Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser->ConditionalFactor()
#7 .../Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1899): Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser->ConditionalTerm()
#8 .../Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1218): Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser->ConditionalExpression()
#9 .../Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(769): Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser->WhereClause()
#10 .../Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(738): Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser->SelectStatement()
#11 .../Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(210): Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser->QueryLanguage()
#12 .../Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(281): Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser->getAST()
#13 .../Doctrine/ORM/Query.php(203): Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser->parse()
#14 .../Doctrine/ORM/Query.php(223): Doctrine/ORM/Query->_parse()
#15 .../Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php(586): Doctrine/ORM/Query->_doExecute()
#16 .../Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php(392): Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery->execute(Array, 1)
```

What I tried was that:

```
$regex = '^[0-9]';
$em
    ->createQuery('
        SELECT t
        FROM MyEntity t
        WHERE t.visible = true 
            AND t.name RLIKE ?1
        ORDER BY t.name ASC')
    ->setParameter(1, $regex)
    ->getResult();
```

and that:

```
$regex = '^[0-9]';
$em
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('t')
    ->from('MyEntity', 't')
    ->where('t.visible = true')
    ->andWhere(new Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Comparison('t.name', 'RLIKE', '?1'))
    ->orderBy('t.name', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->setParameter(1, $regex)
    ->getResult();
```

Do you have any idea, how I could use RLIKE in DQL?

Best regards ;)

Answer (score 1):

Good question, unfortunately I don't have a good answer.

The only thing that comes to mind is to create your own DQL function, like mentioned in the [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language). Good luck with that ;)

Also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574760/regex-with-doctrine-2-query-builder), maybe it will help.

If you solve this problem, please post an answer.