# MySQL query exception when using regex in query

Tags: php, mysql, regex

PHP (Symfony 2.0):

```
$term = "3";

$query = $em->createQuery(
     "SELECT * FROM SoftsystemSupportBundle:Shop WHERE sid REGEXP '^$term'"
);

$shops = $query->getResult();
```

Throws an exception:

> Error: Expected IdentificationVariable | StateFieldPathExpression |
>   AggregateExpression | \"(\" Subselect \")\" | ScalarExpression, got
>   '*'"

I want to get all entities where sid field matches regex.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: Can't help you with a direct answer, but why not try it on SQLFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a misuse of the QueryBuilder object returned by the CreateQuery() method.

You are writing DQL (Doctrine Query Language) and not MySQL. REGEXP is not a DQL keyword, hence the error.

You have the same issue of this post: [Using REGEXP in Doctrine 2.X ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810442/using-regexp-in-doctrine-2-x-orm).

A solution is given there.