# Doctrine ORM: Regex match with DQL function in Expression builder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a [`REGEX()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29034983/519333) DQL function registered in Doctrine ORM.

Now, I want to use that function in Expression builder

```php
$expr = $queryBuilder->expr();
$or = $expr->orX();
$or->add($expr->eq("REGEX(s.field, '[a-z]+')", true));
```

This is not working for me since it is converted to `s0_.field :: TEXT ~ '[a-z]' = 1` which throws in Postgres as it's comparing boolean with int:

> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer.

I also tried avoiding the dql function with `$or->add("s.field ~ '[a-z]+')")` but `~` operator is not supported by ORM.

---

My DQL function is built as

```php
    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker): string
    {
        return sprintf(
            '%s :: TEXT %s %s',
            $this->fieldExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker),
            '~',
            $this->patternExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker),
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace an operator to a function

```sql
-- nameregexeq
SELECT oprname, oprcode
FROM pg_operator
WHERE oprname = '~';

-- example
SELECT TEXTREGEXEQ('a', '[a-z]'), TEXTREGEXEQ('1', '[a-z]')
```

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Node;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

/**
 * Function: JSONB_EXISTS(jsonb, text). Implementation of ? operator.
 */
class JsonbExistsFunc extends FunctionNode
{
    public Node $jsonb;
    public Node $text;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        $jsonb = $this->jsonb->dispatch($sqlWalker);
        $text = $this->text->dispatch($sqlWalker);

        return sprintf('JSONB_EXISTS(%s, %s)', $jsonb, $text);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER); // JSONB_EXISTS
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS); // (
        $this->jsonb = $parser->StringPrimary(); // first arg
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA); //,
        $this->text = $parser->StringPrimary(); // second arg
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS); // )
    }
}

/*
# config/packages/doctrine.yaml
orm:
  entity_managers:
    default:
      dql:
        string_functions:
          JSONB_EXISTS: App\Doctrine\Func\JsonbExistsFunc
*/

// ->andWhere('JSONB_EXISTS(column, CAST(:key AS TEXT))')
```

Comment: Interesting stuff but it does not help drilling it through doctrine orm's dql expression builder.

Comment: I made an implementation of JSONB_EXISTS function, use it as an example.

Comment: But in the first line on my Q I stated I have a DQL function. The problem is how to use it within expression builder.

Comment: Try to use a parameter `$expr->eq("REGEX(s.field, '[a-z]+')", ':true')->setParameter('true', true)`